# 'regex' type not recognized

Tags: c++, regex

I'm facing a weird problem.
First, here's my code :

```
#ifndef REGEX_H
#define REGEX_H

#include <regex>

/******************************  REGEX  *************************/
class MyRegex {
 regex reg;
 StrategieLitteraux* strategie;

public :
 MyRegex(regex _reg, StrategieLitteraux* _strategie) : reg(_reg), strategie(_strategie) {}
 virtual ~MyRegex() {}
 void execute(Pile& pile,const QString& s) { strategie->execute(pile,s); }
 regex getRegex() const {return reg;}

};
/*******************************************************************/
#endif // REGEX_H
```

And I'm getting this error :

> 'regex' does not name a type

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Does anyone have any idea ? I've already used regex before, but this time I can't make it work. Thanks

Comment: You need `std::regex`.

Comment: You are looking for `std::regex`. P.S. I would like to congratulate you for avoiding the mind-rotting cancer called "using namespace std;".

Comment: Thanks ! I'm on Qt and it looks like I don't even need std::regex. I just needed to include "strategie.h", and it recognized regex. I do not know why, but if I ever get this error I'll use std::regex :)
Edit : Actually I know, strategie.h includes computer.h, which uses 'using name std'. I'll delete this line.

Answer (score 3):

`regex` is part of the `std` namespace. You need to use `std::regex`.

Comment: Thanks :) See my comment above.

Comment: @Chuck Your question doesn't reflect the problem you are expressing in that comment. You should edit your question.